# pymongo query to fetch the documents and its child-documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have following documents in collection.

```
{
 "_id": Object('sjaflj'),
 "employee_id": "23849823432",
 "name": "employee-1",
 "department": "department-1",
 "type": "manager",
 "associations" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "associated_components",
        "values" : [ 
            "45c10396cefa7351b1ddadf6d6a29c37"
        ]
    }
]
}

# Document-2
{
 "_id": Object('sjafljwerq'),
 "employee_id": "45c10396cefa7351b1ddadf6d6a29c37",
 "name": "employee-2",
 "department": "department-1",
 "type": "employee",
 "associations" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "associated_components",
        "values" : []
    }
]
}
```

I am fetching documents from db based on name, department, type. i would like to fetch all child-document if the type of record is "manager".

The child-records's key attached to manager is in the associations-->values.

How i can get all the records + child-records from collection using single query. ?

Please suggest some ideas, it will be very helpful. thanks.

Comment: Could you explain it bit more

Comment: Suppose you have two collection in your db one is manager and employee. manager collection will have details of reportee in association tag and employee collection  association tag will be empty. 
So if i fetch the manager record , i would like to get manager and manager's reportee records.